# Error when trying to get sun.runtime.Name is undefined

Tags: java, coldfusion

I am trying to get some info on the internal of my ColdFusion site

```
struct function get_site_info() output="false"  {

var oSystem = createObject('java','java.lang.System');
var jremodel    = oSystem.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
var jrename     = oSystem.getProperty("sun.runtime.name");
var jreversion  = oSystem.getProperty("sun.runtime.version");



var stResult = {CFVERSION = server.ColdFusion.ProductVersion, 
    CFLEVEL = server.ColdFusion.ProductLevel,
    JRENAME = jrename, // Error happens here
    JREVERSION = jreversion };

return stResult;
}
```

The error message is

```
Variable JRENAME is undefined.
```

Comment: what happens if you add a writeoutput("jrename is " & jrename & " and is defined") after you assign it a value from oSystem?

Comment: jrename doesn't have a value - getProperty returns null if you specify a key that doesn't exist.

Comment: As an aside, you can avoid nulls by supplying a default ie `getProperty(name, default)`. In this case the error is probably a good thing. But defaults can come in handy for optional properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such property as "sun.runtime.name", (or indeed sun.runtime.anything).

You probably want **java.runtime.name**.

To see all available properties for the system, do:

```
<cfdump var=#createObject('java','java.lang.System').getProperties()# />
```